# java how to split string from end

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string like "test.test.test"...".test" and i need to access last "test" word in this string. Note that the number of "test" in the string is unlimited. if java had a method like php `explode` function, everything was right, but... . I think splitting from end of string, can solve my problem.
Is there any way to specify direction for `split` method?
I know one solution for this problem can be like this:

```
String parts[] = fileName.split(".");
//for all parts, while a parts contain "." character, split a part...
```

but i think this bad solution.

Comment: Note: Use `\\.`, as `.` has special meaning in regex (what `split` expects).

Comment: If you only need the last dot, find it with `lastIndexOf` and then use `substring` instead of splitting the all string.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try substring with lastIndexOf method of String:

```
String str = "almas.test.tst";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
Output:
tst
```

Comment: `fails for input without "." do remember to test if lastIndexOf(".") != -1`

Comment: @AnilMuppalla actually, it doesn't fail but rather return the whole word, as expected when not finding the delimiter.



`System.out.println("no-dots-whatsoever".substring("no-dots-whatsoever".lastIndexOf(".") + 1));


-->no-dots-whatsoever`

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use `lastIndexOf(String str)` method for this purpose.

```
String str = "test.test.test....test";

int pos = str.lastIndexOf("test");

String result = str.substring(pos);
```