# Split string in reverse

Tags: java, string

I have a string `sub1-sub2-sub3` which I want to split from right to left. Currently I am using split function like this which splits the string from left to right -

```
String str = "sub1-sub2-sub3";
System.out.println("Result :" + str.split("-", 2));
```

Elements in output :

```
sub1
sub2-sub3
```

Desired output :

```
sub1-sub2
sub3
```

Is there a way where I can split my string on `-` starting from right?

Comment: Why do you expect 2 rather than 3 list elements?

Comment: @jorn reversing the list would still give me the same elements but in reversed order.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have some business logic I need the ```sub1-sub2``` part for some validation. I don't care how many ```-``` are in the string, but all I need is to split it in two parts. One should be the first from right and second should be the rest.

Comment: Why not just use lastIndexOf() and substring yourself on that?

Comment: just did it. @GhostCat

Answer (score 3):

You could do a regex split on `-(?!.*-)`:

```java
String str = "sub1-sub2-sub3";
String[] parts = str.split("-(?!.*-)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));  // [sub1-sub2, sub3]
```

The regex pattern used here will only match the final dash.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution as utility method that takes limit as input with java 8:

```
public List<String> splitReverse(String input, String regex, int limit) {
    return Arrays.stream(reverse(input).split(regex, limit))
            .map(this::reverse)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private String reverse(String i){
    return new StringBuilder(i).reverse().toString();
}
```

`reverse()` code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7569335/8283737)

Input: `sub1-sub2-sub3`

Reverse input: `3bus-2bus-1bus`

Split(rev,2): `[3bus] , [2bus-1bus]`

Reverse each: `[sub3] , [sub1-sub2]`

Comment: You might want to add the significant performance impact, compared to a straight forward solution that splits on a more complicated regex or that simply uses lastIndexOf() and substring.

Comment: Agreed. But `lastIndexOf` hardwires the limit to 2 which doesn't make justice to the question title.

Comment: Well, the question isn't really clear what the user would expect for a-b-c-d to happen ...

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to reverse the string before the split and then reverse the resulting strings.

```
String str = "sub1-sub2-sub3";
Arrays.stream(StringUtils.reverse(str).split("-",2))
      .map(StringUtils::reverse)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
sub3
sub1-sub2
```

It won't yield the same result as requested but maybe it will help.

P.S. util class used is from apache: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution i cam up with would be

```
    String str = "sub1-sub2-sub3";
    str = StringUtils.reverse(str);

    String[] split = str.split("-", 2);
    split[0] = StringUtils.reverse(split[0]);
    split[1] = StringUtils.reverse(split[1]);

    System.out.println("Result :" + split[0] + " #### " + split[1]);
```

another way would be [java how to split string from end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763984/java-how-to-split-string-from-end)

Comment: import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me fine :

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("-"));
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-"));
```